# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine MongoDB ODM and Apache too slow

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, virtualbox, doctrine-mongodb

We're experiencing strange performance issues running:

- [Zend Framework 2.3.3](http://framework.zend.com/) on PHP 5.5.18-1
- Doctrine MongoDB ODM Module (https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb, https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule)
- Ubuntu 12.04 on VirtualBox via [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) (https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64)

We know for sure that this is **not** a DB issue (tried it with a real MongoDB instance, still same result).

---

## Scenario

We have defined objects that work with Doctrine ODM in a manner similar to this:

```
<?php

namespace CatalogueManager\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/*
 * @ODM\Document(repositoryClass="CatalogueManager\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Item
{
    /** @ODM\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $name;

    /** @ODM\Timestamp */
    protected $created;

    /** @ODM\Timestamp */
    protected $updated;

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    /**
     * Return properties as an array. Helper method to assist with converting
     * doctrine objects to arrays so we can return front-end api calls as json.
     *
     * Required as currently Doctrine ODM do not support array hydration of
     * referenced documents.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array
     *
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        $arr = ['id'          => $this->id,
                'name'        => $this->name,
                'urlSlug'     => $this->urlSlug,
                'desc'        => $this->desc,
                'metaData'    => $this->metadata,
                'category'    => $this->category,
                'brand'       => $this->brand,
                'assets'      => $this->assets,
                'shipping'    => $this->shipping,
                'specs'       => $this->specs,
                'attrs'       => $this->attrs,
                'optionTypes' => $this->optionTypes
                ];

        return $arr;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    /**
     * Getter
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     *
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Getter
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     *
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    /**
     * Setter
     *
     * @param string $value Property value
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     *
     */
    public function setName($value)
    {
        $this->name = $value;
    }

}
```

We're using these to import approx. 100 products into a product database. This all takes about 5 seconds on a real machine but when trying on a **virtual machine**, it takes approx. ***25 seconds*** to do the same thing.

Looks like the problem could be **Apache** which is taking **99% load** while this all is being processed, yet I'm having difficulty pinpointing what's really going on.

Any kind of advice would be appreciated...

---

## Update

This only seems to occur when **writing** data. Reading data seems to be ok.

Webgrind data (screenshot) available: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjlg7ano6epy6t1/webgrind.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at some of your screenshots of XDebug data, I think you are simply using the ORM/ODM in the wrong way, since you are batch processing > 13K results.

The correct solution for this sort of operation is explained at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

What is happening is very simple:
 - the ODM loads one record from the DB
 - the ODM stores that record into the `UnitOfWork`
 - on flush, the ODM iterates over all entries in the `UnitOfWork`, looking for changed documents/entities

If you keep storing more data in the `UnitOfWork`, then obviously the iteration is going to take longer times at every repetition of the operation.

You should call `ObjectManager#clear()` between batch chunks being processed.

Answer (score 1):

So this won't be an answer, I'll aim for advise. It's normal for things to run slower on a local machine, let alone on a virtual one.

Things that might be of some help:

1. You can make your virtual machine have more memory by adding this to your vagrant file

`config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
end`

2. Also use the zf2 module [ZendDeveloperTools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools), which will show you what time your requests, rounting, db queries(it works with doctrine) and what not are taking. And you can pinpoint whatever is running slow.

And just a side note. Why are you running php 5.5 on a 12.04, why not a 14.04 (it's trustier, but not so precise). It's easier to set it up.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :) The VM already has 4GB of memory and 2 processors assigned and we do use ZDT but there is nothing visible in any of the debug information that would tell us what's taking so long. I've echoed each step manually to the browser as well and it's basically just taking much more time to write into DB than it's doing outside the VM. This is using VM's native filesystem and that in itself has been super fast for us so far. The only problem is this Mongo thing, thus I'm asking here :P And we started with 12.04 and are using Puppet to spin up our dev instances, thus the reason